# How do i finish one task before going to another in JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm using mongoose and want to use .insertMany() and wait it to finish before using .find() operation. Can't figure out how to do it using async/await .

```
    Fruit.insertMany([kivi,orange,mango],function(e) {
    if(e) {console.log(err);}
   else { console.log("operation succesful: saved all fruits to DB");}
   });



 Fruit.find({name:'kivi'}  ,function(e, fruits){
  if(e)  console.log(e);
  else   console.log(fruits);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use .then().catch() or async/await.

1. Using .then().catch():

```
    Fruit.insertMany([kivi, orange, mango])
    .then(result => {
    console.log('operation succesful: saved all fruits to DB')
    Fruit.find({ name: 'kivi' })
    .then(fruits => {
    console.log(fruits)
    })
    .catch(err => {
    console.log(err.message)
    })
    })
    .catch(err => {
    console.log(err.message)
    }

)
```

2. Using async/await:

```
    router.post('/fruit-test',async(req,res)=>{
    try {
    await Fruit.insertMany([kivi, orange, mango])
    console.log('operation succesful: saved all fruits to DB')
    const fruits = await Fruit.find({ name: 'kivi' })
    console.log(fruits)
    } catch (err) {
    console.log(err.message)
    }
    })
```

For more async/await help check [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/node/current/usage-examples/insertMany/)